# Varying the axes of a seaborn displot to save space

Tags: python, seaborn

I used the code below to generate the image attached to this question:

```
import seaborn as sns
plot = sns.displot(data=df, col='threshold', col_wrap=2, x='predicted_synonym_count', hue='has_synonym', multiple='stack', binwidth=0.5)
plot.savefig('my_file_name.jpg')
```

The image is extremely tall because the top two plots, especially the one labeled threshold=0.02, have very tall bins. None of the other plots have bins that are that tall, but they all have the same y-axis range as the top two images. Is it possible using a seaborn displot or something similar to reduce the size of the y-axis for the lower eight plots while keeping the top two plots as they are?

[image: A displot consisting of ten histograms representing the predicted number of synonyms for each label, colored according to whether the label has any actual synonyms.]

**UPDATE:** I made a version of the plot I'm looking for in Krita out of the original plot, so that you can see what my goal is. It is below.

[image: A modified version of the displot above, in which the heights of each histogram pair are adjusted based on the maximum bin height.]

Comment: Check out this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480622/plot-each-chart-on-a-different-scale-with-seaborn-distplot).

Comment: That's very helpful and good to know about, but what I would really like would be if I could have them at the same scale, but with different heights, as opposed to at the same heights with different scales.